# Where + FirstOrDefault(). ArgumentNullException Value cannot be null

Tags: asp.net-mvc, exception, events, nullpointerexception, nullreferenceexception

I cant open a detail page on the online website for some reason. On the local website it does work, i checked in the event viewer and this is what i got:

```
ArgumentNullException 
   Value cannot be null. Parameter name: source at System.Linq.Enumerable.Where[TSource](IEnumerable`1 source, Func`2 predicate) at ASP._Page_Views_Shared__LoginPartial_cshtml.Execute() in d:\inetpub\wwwroot\TestMap\Views\Shared\_LoginPartial.cshtml:line 30 at System.Web.WebPages.WebPageBase.ExecutePageHierarchy() at System.Web.Mvc.WebViewPage.ExecutePageHierarchy() at System.Web.WebPages.WebPageBase.ExecutePageHierarchy(WebPageContext pageContext, TextWriter writer, WebPageRenderingBase startPage) at System.Web.Mvc.Html.PartialExtensions.Partial(HtmlHelper htmlHelper, String partialViewName, Object model, ViewDataDictionary viewData) at ASP._Page_Views_Shared__TopNavbar_cshtml.Execute() in d:\inetpub\wwwroot\TestMap\Views\Shared\_TopNavbar.cshtml:line 13 at System.Web.WebPages.WebPageBase.ExecutePageHierarchy() at System.Web.Mvc.WebViewPage.ExecutePageHierarchy() at System.Web.WebPages.WebPageBase.ExecutePageHierarchy(WebPageContext pageContext, TextWriter writer, WebPageRenderingBase startPage) at System.Web.Mvc.Html.PartialExtensions.Partial(HtmlHelper htmlHelper, String partialViewName, Object model, ViewDataDictionary viewData) at ASP._Page_Views_Shared__Layout_cshtml.Execute() in d:\inetpub\wwwroot\TestMap\Views\Shared\_Layout.cshtml:line 73 at System.Web.WebPages.WebPageBase.ExecutePageHierarchy() at System.Web.Mvc.WebViewPage.ExecutePageHierarchy() at System.Web.WebPages.WebPageBase.ExecutePageHierarchy(WebPageContext pageContext, TextWriter writer, WebPageRenderingBase startPage) at System.Web.WebPages.WebPageBase.<>c__DisplayClass40_0.<RenderPageCore>b__0(TextWriter writer) at System.Web.WebPages.WebPageBase.Write(HelperResult result) at System.Web.WebPages.WebPageBase.RenderSurrounding(String partialViewName, Action`1 body) at System.Web.WebPages.WebPageBase.PopContext() at System.Web.Mvc.ViewResultBase.ExecuteResult(ControllerContext context) at System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncControllerActionInvoker.<>c__DisplayClass3_1.<BeginInvokeAction>b__5(IAsyncResult asyncResult) at System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncControllerActionInvoker.EndInvokeAction(IAsyncResult asyncResult) at System.Web.Mvc.Controller.<>c.<BeginExecuteCore>b__152_1(IAsyncResult asyncResult, ExecuteCoreState innerState) at System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncResultWrapper.WrappedAsyncVoid`1.CallEndDelegate(IAsyncResult asyncResult) at System.Web.Mvc.Controller.EndExecuteCore(IAsyncResult asyncResult) at System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncResultWrapper.WrappedAsyncVoid`1.CallEndDelegate(IAsyncResult asyncResult) at System.Web.Mvc.Controller.EndExecute(IAsyncResult asyncResult) at System.Web.Mvc.MvcHandler.<>c.<BeginProcessRequest>b__20_1(IAsyncResult asyncResult, ProcessRequestState innerState) at System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncResultWrapper.WrappedAsyncVoid`1.CallEndDelegate(IAsyncResult asyncResult) at System.Web.Mvc.MvcHandler.EndProcessRequest(IAsyncResult asyncResult) at System.Web.HttpApplication.CallHandlerExecutionStep.InvokeEndHandler(IAsyncResult ar) at System.Web.HttpApplication.CallHandlerExecutionStep.OnAsyncHandlerCompletion(IAsyncResult ar)  
   at System.Linq.Enumerable.Where[TSource](IEnumerable`1 source, Func`2 predicate) at ASP._Page_Views_Shared__LoginPartial_cshtml.Execute() in d:\inetpub\wwwroot\TestMap\Views\Shared\_LoginPartial.cshtml:line 30 at System.Web.WebPages.WebPageBase.ExecutePageHierarchy() at System.Web.Mvc.WebViewPage.ExecutePageHierarchy() at System.Web.WebPages.WebPageBase.ExecutePageHierarchy(WebPageContext pageContext, TextWriter writer, WebPageRenderingBase startPage) at System.Web.Mvc.Html.PartialExtensions.Partial(HtmlHelper htmlHelper, String partialViewName, Object model, ViewDataDictionary viewData) at ASP._Page_Views_Shared__TopNavbar_cshtml.Execute() in d:\inetpub\wwwroot\TestMap\Views\Shared\_TopNavbar.cshtml:line 13 at System.Web.WebPages.WebPageBase.ExecutePageHierarchy() at System.Web.Mvc.WebViewPage.ExecutePageHierarchy() at System.Web.WebPages.WebPageBase.ExecutePageHierarchy(WebPageContext pageContext, TextWriter writer, WebPageRenderingBase startPage) at System.Web.Mvc.Html.PartialExtensions.Partial(HtmlHelper htmlHelper, String partialViewName, Object model, ViewDataDictionary viewData) at ASP._Page_Views_Shared__Layout_cshtml.Execute() in d:\inetpub\wwwroot\TestMap\Views\Shared\_Layout.cshtml:line 73 at System.Web.WebPages.WebPageBase.ExecutePageHierarchy() at System.Web.Mvc.WebViewPage.ExecutePageHierarchy() at System.Web.WebPages.WebPageBase.ExecutePageHierarchy(WebPageContext pageContext, TextWriter writer, WebPageRenderingBase startPage) at System.Web.WebPages.WebPageBase.<>c__DisplayClass40_0.<RenderPageCore>b__0(TextWriter writer) at System.Web.WebPages.WebPageBase.Write(HelperResult result) at System.Web.WebPages.WebPageBase.RenderSurrounding(String partialViewName, Action`1 body) at System.Web.WebPages.WebPageBase.PopContext() at System.Web.Mvc.ViewResultBase.ExecuteResult(ControllerContext context) at System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncControllerActionInvoker.<>c__DisplayClass3_1.<BeginInvokeAction>b__5(IAsyncResult asyncResult) at System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncControllerActionInvoker.EndInvokeAction(IAsyncResult asyncResult) at System.Web.Mvc.Controller.<>c.<BeginExecuteCore>b__152_1(IAsyncResult asyncResult, ExecuteCoreState innerState) at System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncResultWrapper.WrappedAsyncVoid`1.CallEndDelegate(IAsyncResult asyncResult) at System.Web.Mvc.Controller.EndExecuteCore(IAsyncResult asyncResult) at System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncResultWrapper.WrappedAsyncVoid`1.CallEndDelegate(IAsyncResult asyncResult) at System.Web.Mvc.Controller.EndExecute(IAsyncResult asyncResult) at System.Web.Mvc.MvcHandler.<>c.<BeginProcessRequest>b__20_1(IAsyncResult asyncResult, ProcessRequestState innerState) at System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncResultWrapper.WrappedAsyncVoid`1.CallEndDelegate(IAsyncResult asyncResult) at System.Web.Mvc.MvcHandler.EndProcessRequest(IAsyncResult asyncResult) at System.Web.HttpApplication.CallHandlerExecutionStep.InvokeEndHandler(IAsyncResult ar) at System.Web.HttpApplication.CallHandlerExecutionStep.OnAsyncHandlerCompletion(IAsyncResult ar)
```

I really dont know where to look / where the problem is

Here is some code:

```
(line 28)if (controller != "Home")
                            {
                                var defaultActionForController = ((List<DefaultActionForControllers>)ViewBag.DefaultActionsForControllers).Where(s => s.Controller == controller).Select(s => s.Action).FirstOrDefault();
                                if (controller == "ManagementObjects")
                                {
                                    var controllerName = firstLayerNameSet;
                                    @:> @Html.ActionLink(firstLayerNameSet, defaultActionForController, controller)
                                }
                                else if (controller == "MangementCategories")
                                {
                                    var controllerName = secondLayerNameSet;
                                    @:> @Html.ActionLink(secondLayerNameSet, defaultActionForController, controller)
                                }
                                else if (controller == "View")
                                {
                                    @:> @Html.ActionLink(Resources.ResourceManager.GetString(controller), "", "")
                                }
                                else
                                {
                                    @:> @Html.ActionLink(Resources.ResourceManager.GetString(controller), defaultActionForController, controller)
                                }
(line 50)                   }
```

After debugging the code above here i saw that defaultActionForController is null. And after hovering over the firstordefault() i saw it says Exceptions: ArgumentNullException

Comment: start here: Shared_LoginPartial.cshtml:line 30, it would be nice to see some code, otherwise its hard to help

Comment: @JurijB i added some code, its just the if statement. If you want i can just add the whole code tho!

Comment: @JurijB i went and debugged on the local site. And it says that defaultActionForController is null. Do you know why?

Comment: Please don't make more work for other people by vandalizing your posts. By posting on the Stack Exchange network, you've granted a non-revocable right, under the [CC BY-SA 4.0 license](//creativecommons.org/licenses/by-sa/4.0/), for Stack Exchange to distribute that content (i.e. regardless of your future choices). By Stack Exchange policy, the non-vandalized version of the post is the one which is distributed. Thus, any vandalism will be reverted. If you want to know more about deleting a post please see: [How does deleting work?](//meta.stackexchange.com/q/5221)